# Can we install eucalyptus on single computer?

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing, cloud-hosting, eucalyptus

I want to learn about Eucalyptus cloud computing. I have read few documentation pages on eucalyptus website but im still confused about some parts of it.

I have downloaded Eucalyptus and Eucatools.

I would like to know whether we can install all the components needed (Walrus, NC,etc.) for Eucalyptus on single computer in single OS?

Or do I need to create different virtual machines in order to use those components?

I have one more question. Why do we need to connect to Eucalyptus community cloud? What does it offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need at least two computers to get started. One will be the cloud 'servers' (CLC, WC, CC and SC) the other will be the cloud 'node' (NC). The node computer must have hardware-virtualization enabled CPUs.

This document really helped me getting my first cloud off the ground:
http://cssoss.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/pdf-version-of-eucalyptus-beginners-guide-uec-edition/

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer - you can definitely install Eucalyptus onto one host machine - I did it myself yesterday.  See their 'Fast Start' download at http://www.eucalyptus.com/download/faststart

Answer (score 1):

You do not need two computers. You can have all the Eucalyptus services installed on one computer and also use this same computer to start the virtual machines on.

Also hardware virtualization is only required when you use KVM. If you use Xen instead you can also do paravirtualization.

Last time I check Ubuntu was a good choice for Eucalyptus and KVM. For Eucalyptus and Xen I had some good experience with OpenSUSE in the past. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to learn more about how the platform work I'd recommend to try Faststart http://www.eucalyptus.com/eucalyptus-cloud/get-started/try#faststart 
It's an easy way to have a working Eucalyptus cloud in less than one hour. You only need a machine with 100GB of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can install Eucalyptus with all basic essential components on the same machine.

In faststart, there is setup called Cloud in a box will install Cloud on a single machine 
without any hassles.

> https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#faststart-guide/install_cloud_in_a_box.html

As​ you want to start from the basics this option is highly recommended.

And in case of Eucalyptus community cloud, you will be offered with instances & machines

images from Eucalyptus to experiment & understand without installation physically. That's

all.